# PHP Fatal error: require_once()

Tags: php

As soon as I move my files to my host (at namecheap through Filezilla), only the navbar loads - I use the "codecourse" (previously phpacademy) OOP login/registration system, and the problem seems to be in the classes "../class/xxx.php" being called in "../core/init.php" - I haven't touched any of those files other than changing datebase, but no code has been touched.

The error log (error_log);
http://pastebin.com/eZsKrftm

My 'classes' folder;
[image]

../core/init.php line 21;

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/' . $class . '.php');
```

I have **no** idea how to fix this, I did everything the error_log says is wrong really, I tried renaming all the classes to have a capital front-letter, but that doesn't seem to be it...

The weirdest part about this, is that it works just fine locally (xampp).

Comment: In your log, `PHP Warning:  require_once(classes/Cookie.php)` has an uppercase `C` when your file `cookie.php` has not.

Comment: Your own `dev` environment was Windows obviously, and now that you have moved your site to Unix Bases systems they are suddenly case sensitive with file names :)

Comment: I tried that as well. As I said in the post... made the first letter capital, but it didn't do a difference

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Don't be sure OS X is case insensitive by default..

Comment: @Svetlio I am ;) All unix based systems, including OSX are case-sensitive. AFAIK you cannot change this (and why would you?)

Comment: @giorgio lets not make that a chat but if you have installed Mac you should know that the default installation image is not case sensitive (there is and case sensitive option of course)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using upper case while using the files but your files are in lower case,

Use `strtolower()`, for this

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/' . strtolower($class) . '.php');
                                                       ^                 ^
```

Comment: Jesus christ, okay, now it doesn't work on my localhost, xampp.
Is there like, a "fix" for BOTH platforms?